# No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 74.125.25.109:993

Tags: c#, imap, tcpclient, gmail-imap, imapx

Hi I am trying to connect to gmail using ImapX library in C#.
But getting error like this No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 74.125.25.109:993 while creating TcpClient (inside ImapX).
I browse few same questions on stackoverflow but none was helpful to me.

Here is my code.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var client = new ImapClient("imap.gmail.com",993, true);
    client.SslProtocol = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Ssl2;
    client.UseSsl = true;
    if (client.Connect()) // This method creates new instance of TcpClient which throws error so returning false from catch block method has been described below.
    {

        if (client.Login("example@gmail.com", "example123"))
        {
            // login successful
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Connection Successful...!");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Connection UnSuccessful...!");
        Console.ReadLine();
        // connection not successful
    }
}
```

Here is Client method in ImapX library.

```
public bool Connect(string host, int port, SslProtocols sslProtocol = SslProtocols.None,
    bool validateServerCertificate = true)
{
    _host = host;
    _port = port;
    _sslProtocol = sslProtocol;
    _validateServerCertificate = validateServerCertificate;

    if (IsConnected)
        throw new InvalidStateException("The client is already connected. Please disconnect first.");

    try
    {

        _client = new TcpClient(_host, _port);
        if (_sslProtocol == SslProtocols.None)
        {
            _ioStream = _client.GetStream();
            _streamReader = new StreamReader(_ioStream);
        }
        else
        {
            _ioStream = new SslStream(_client.GetStream(), false, CertificateValidationCallback, null);
            (_ioStream as SslStream).AuthenticateAsClient(_host, null, _sslProtocol, false);
            _streamReader = new StreamReader(_ioStream);
        }


        string result = _streamReader.ReadLine();

        _lastActivity = DateTime.Now;

        if (result != null && result.StartsWith(ResponseType.ServerOk))
        {
            Capability();
            return true;
        }
        else if (result != null && result.StartsWith(ResponseType.ServerPreAuth))
        {
            IsAuthenticated = true;
            Capability();
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (!IsConnected)
            CleanUp();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I use Telenet then I am getting like this. Microsoft Telnet> open imap.gmail.com 993
Connecting To imap.gmail.com...Could not open connection to the host, on port 99
3: Connect failed

Comment: Are you able to connect with some mail client sw such as thunderbird? Do you have any proxy configured?

Comment: @František Žiačik I am not sure about thunderbird instead I am using Windows Live mail as my mail client and I do not have any proxy configured.

Comment: Did you try different protocols? Like client.SslProtocol = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Default. I would expect  SSl2 is fine, but you never know.

Comment: @bastijn yes none of them is working and I have tried connecting pop server using openpop that works fine with me but I need to perform mail transfer using Imap only.

Comment: Your code looks decent on first sight. Maybe have a look at google's OAuth and dont forget to register your application in your google account? First google hit: http://www.limilabs.com/blog/oauth2-gmail-imap-service-account .

Comment: Somebody is blocking you.  Could be your firewall.  Could by a proxy.  Could be your anti-malware.  Could be Google because your IP address was used to send way too much spam.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks Hans on the another machine my code gets working there is something which is blocking me.Thank you to all for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're using ImapX with GMail, the following code is enough to establish the connection:

```
var client = new ImapClient("imap.gmail.com", true);
if (client.Connect()) {
    // ...
}
```

It will use SSL with the standard 993 port. If you want to specify the SSL version manually, for GMail you need to use `SslProtocols.Default`, which is equivalent to `SslProtocols.Ssl3 | SslProtocols.Tls`

Comment: You are right. The problem was with my machine and network who was not allowing me to connect to imap.gmail.com on port 993. I tried with another machine and it started working. Thanks for your time.